# Manage password complexity in Youtrack

Tags: passwords, credentials, youtrack, server-administration

Is it possible, with Youtrack 6.x, to:

- enforce a password minimal complexity for all user accounts ?
- reset all passwords at once ?

So far, I'm only able to change passwords, one user at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such functionality is not available in YouTrack.